# Init service not starting in user build

Tags: aosp, init.d

I have an init service that is not starting in user build. When running a userdebug build it works fine but not in user build. Can't seem to figure out why it's not running. I don't see any errors about it in logcat either.

```
on property:myprop=1
    start mysvc

service mysvc /system/bin/mybinary myargs
    user system
    group system
    oneshot
```

My app sets this property when I want the service to start.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Is `/data/logs/` accessible to `system` UID for writing? What's the SELinux context of the service? Can it access `/data/logs/`? See kernel log for `init` services.

Comment: Yes, `system` UID has access to the folder, which is why it works in userdebug build. I'm not worried about SELinux just yet; my build is running under permissive mode.

Comment: Just had a look at the kernel log and nothing in there either. My property `myprop` does get set appropriately but the service is not running.

Comment: Which Android version you are on? Set `seclabel` and try again.

Comment: I am running Android 8. Looking into trying with `seclabel`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Using `seclabel` worked. Why is that, when I have set the service to be user/group `system` already?

Comment: Can't remember exactly why, need to look into code. But this is the behavior in recent Android releases.

Comment: Ok, I see it now, the default context doesn't have enough permission. I'll have make sure I give it enough permission then, but not over do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the SELinux context that the process was running under. I was able to fix it by marking the `seclabel` of my init service.

```
on property:myprop=1
    start mysvc

service mysvc /system/bin/mybinary myargs
    user system
    group system
    oneshot
    seclabel u:r:su:s0
```